# D3 d3.text request function bug

Tags: javascript, text, callback, d3.js

The updated (mbostock-d3-dd2a424) d3.text() function no longer successfully reads my local files. I am seeing a "0" request status so the code below always returns null:

var s = req.status;
callback(s >= 200 && s < 300 || s === 304 ? req : null);

The mbostock-d3-af2af6a version works for my local file reads:
callback(req.status < 300 ? req : null);

Is this a bug? Can I call d3.text(fileNameList, callback) differently to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for this in [pull request #632](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/632), however, you shouldn't use d3.text (and more generally XMLHttpRequest) to read local files. You should use a local web server instead. For example, if you run:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000 &`

Then you can access `http://localhost:8000` to view your files.